# How to convert a string with digits and operators to a number?

Tags: vb.net, string, type-conversion

I have a problem with converting `TextBox.Text` to an `Integer`.

The text contains only numbers in this format:
example: `1 + 3 * 6 - (2 - 1)`

How can I convert this textbox (or string) to `Integer` to get the calculated value back?

Nothing I found online helped.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?397264-A-simple-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expressions-using-CodeDom

Comment: or this: https://ncalc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `DataTable` as calculator:

```
Dim calc As New DataTable()
Dim result = CType(calc.Compute("1 + 3 * 6 - (2 - 1)", Nothing), Double) ' 18.0
```

Have a look at the remarks of [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) to see what is supported.

Comment: I tried your code Tim. I inserted textbox1.text to the string named value. Used your code: Dim result = CType(calc.Compute(value, Nothing), Double) and got error: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: @DaliborBoldis: Tim's code works - I just tried it. +1

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Dim value as string = "" ::: value = textbox1.text ::: Dim result = CType(calc.Compute(value, Nothing), Double) and error. I need a way to convert string with 1 + 3 * 6 etc. to integer and calculate it in real time.

Comment: sorry, it works. I just forgot to add label3.text = result.to string. +1 mate :) BIG Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/) (an open source library):

```
Dim e As New NCalc.Expression("1 + 3 * 6 - (2 - 1)")
Console.WriteLine(e.Evaluate) 'prints 18
```

Get [NCalc using NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncalc/):

```
Install-Package ncalc
```

> NCalc is a mathematical expressions evaluator in .NET. NCalc can parse any expression and evaluate the result, including static or dynamic parameters and custom functions.